# missing rows, how to select values

Tags: sql

How to accomplish this: I have bunch of numbers (for example: 2342423; 34443123; 3523423) and some of them are in my database table as primary key value. I want to select only those numbers, which are not in my table. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Some product specific tricks may be used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just a few numbers you can do

```
select tmp.num
from
(
  select 2342423 as num
  union all
  select 34443123
  union all
  select 3523423
) tmp
left join your_table t on t.id = tmp.num
where t.id is null
```

If it is more than a few numbers you should insert these into a table and `left join` against that table like this

```
select twntc.num
from table_with_numbers_to_check twntc    
left join your_table t on t.id = twntc.num
where t.id is null
```